# What is the most efficient way to store a non-directed graph?

Tags: java, graph, graph-theory, directed-graph

As the title says.. What is the most efficient way to store a connected graph in java?

For example lets say I have multiple locations connecting to each other in various ways and I have to traverse through the graph to see if it's connected.. any help/comment would be helpful thanks!

Comment: What you're describing is a graph, not a map.

Comment: Store as in create the object to keep in memory?

Comment: The most efficient way depends on how dense/sparse your graph is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One often used representation is a matrix (two dimensional array) indexed by all the nodes in the graph, where `M[i,j] == true` if there is a directed edge from node `i` to `j`. A variation on the theme is to store the length / weight of the edge between the two nodes (where a missing edge may be represented by the value -1).

Answer (score 1):

use an [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) without the symmetry, thereby representing direction instead of simple adjacency.

Answer (score 1):

Using an [incidence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix) or [adjacency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) matrix will do the trick.

If you use an adjacency matrix, a [sparse matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) might be efficient to use, if you have a lot of nodes. [Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/) provides a sparse matrix implementation. Info taken from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390181/sparse-matrices-arrays-in-java).

Also, I've used [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) sucessfully before, so you might want to take a peek under the hood to see how they've implemented directed graphs.

Answer (score 0):

For lookup efficiency - use a boolean matrix (true if there is an arc connecting the nodes, false if there isn't). For memory efficiency define one of your object properties as a (dynamic) list of objects its pointing to.  Note the latter will only help if you have a LOT of nodes in your graph.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something? The data is already a graph, just serialize it.For the question as written talk of matrices is completely premature.