# Java data structure for matrix?

Tags: java, data-structures, matrix

What is the best data structure I can use for my matrix that will contain short variables but most of elements are empty..

I could simply use n by b array for the matrix but the problem is that I don't want to waste the memory because only a few elements are in the matrix..

I was going to use a linked list or a hash table but not sure which one would be the best data structure and how to implemente this..

Comment: this could help for sparse matrices in java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390181/sparse-matrices-arrays-in-java    if you are going to roll your own, i think the choice of data structure would depend on what kind of operations youll be doing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would implement a [Sparse Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix). Use a `HashMap` with the row index as keys, and then either a `HashMap` or `TreeMap` for the actual elements (with the column index as key). If you are storing primitive types, I would suggest having a look at the [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) Java Collections Framework. It is optimized for use with primitive types. I would suggest using it anyway, as the keys could all be primitive.

Answer (score 1):

There are also multiple [Table](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table) implementations from Google Guava libraries

Answer (score 0):

When the matrix is sparse, its better to use LinkedList. LinkedList will be better than other options in terms of space(provided the matrix is sparse).

But note that LinkedList has O(n) time for access.