# How to access elements within multi-dimensional vector?

Tags: java, vector, multidimensional-array

I need to create a variable-sized two-dimensional coordinate system. What I've been able to come up with so far is:

```
Vector<Coordinate> board = new Vector();

for ( int count = 0; count < num_rows; count++ ) {
  board.add(new Vector(num_cols));
}
```

How do I access the elements within this multi-dimensional vector? I have tried doing `board[row][col]` but this didn't seem to work.

I'm familiar with using Vectors in C++, but can't seem to figure out how to do this in Java.

Comment: Why aren't you just using arrays?

Comment: This may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390181/sparse-matrices-arrays-in-java

Comment: @Henning Makholm - I need to set the dimensions of the grid after I initialize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get how you are adding a Vector into a Vector of Coordinates.
You might try something like List<List<Coordinate>> board. Then use board.get(1).get(2) to get a position.

What you really might try is the Guava Table.
http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release09/javadoc/index.html

Then it would be:

```
Table<Integer, Integer, Coordinate> board;
board.put(1, 2, new Coordinate());
```

Comment: Great, thank you for both clarifying how to declare the multi-dimensional vectors and showing me how to access the element within that vector.

Comment: Any specific reason why you suggested using List<List<Coordinate>> instead of Vector<Vector<Coordinate>>?

Comment: Vectors are thread-safe. If you don't need the overhead of thread-safety, don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html

You need to use .get(index_number) so that becomes board.get(row).get(col)

Answer (score 1):

A vector in Java is more like a list than an array. To access the element at position 0 in vector v, use:

```
v.elementAt(0)
```

or

```
v.get(0)
```

Check the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using two-dimensional array:

```
Coordinate[][] space = new Coordinate[width][height];
...
Coordinate valuableInfo = space[x][y];
```

Comment: I would much rather use arrays, but I need to be able to resize my grid.