# Read lines of numbers from a file to a 2d array using a for loop

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, integer

I want to read lines of numbers from a file. The code is as follows but the IDE shows `NullPointerException` runtime exception. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```java
//reading the contents of the file into an array
public static void readAndStoreNumbers() {
    //initialising the new object
    arr = new int[15][];

    try {
        //create file reader
        File f = new File("E:\\Eclipse Projects\\triangle.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));

        //read from file
        String nums;
        int index = 0;
        while ((nums = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] numbers = nums.split(" ");

            //store the numbers into 'arr' after converting into integers
            for (int i = 0; i < arr[index].length; i++) {
                arr[index][i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
            }
            index++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: which line showing nullpointerexception?

Comment: I would rather us a simple `List` of `List`, with index being the line number and value being the ints.

Answer (score 5):

Your second dimension of `arr` is uninitialized, and you are invoking

```
arr[index].length
```

Answer (score 1):

You could be running into an NPEX for two reasons.

1. You don't finish your definition of `arr` - it's not evident in your code that you declare `arr` as `int arr[][]`;
2. Even if you had the above, you wouldn't have set aside space for your second array.  What you have now is a [jagged array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10271559/1079354); you can have elements of whatever length in the second dimension you wish in your second array.

   The only modification I made to your code to get it to work would be the following line:

   ```
   arr[index] = new int[numbers.length];
   ```

   ...after pulling elements into `numbers`, and before entering the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `StringBuilder`..

```java
//reading the contents of the file into an array
public static void readAndStoreNumbers() {
    //initialising the StringBuffer 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        //create file reader
        File f = new File("E:\\Eclipse Projects\\triangle.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));

        //read from file
        String nums;
        int index = 0;
        while ((nums = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] numbers = nums.split(" ");

            //store the numbers into 'arr' after converting into integers
            for (int i = 0; i < arr[index].length; i++) {
                sb.append(Integer.parseInt(numbers[i])).append("\n");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change -

`for(int i=0; i<arr[index].length; i++) {`

to

```
arr[index] = new int[numbers.length];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have real multidimensional arrays. What you are using is actually an array of int arrays: `new int[n][]` actually creates an array with room for `n` objects of type `int[]`.

Consequently you will have to initialize each of those `int` arrays separately. That would have been obvious from the fact that you never actually specified the length of the second dimension anywhere in your program.