# Need some explanation on 2D String arrays

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

In the nested `for` loop for a basic 2D String array I came across this:

```
 array = new String [5][10];
for(int i=0; i<array.length;i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<array[0].length;j++)
    {
        System.out.print(array[i][j]="*");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Now this is what I want to know, why does the second `for` statement include `array[0].length` rather than `array.length` like in the `for` statement before it?

All I could extract from this while experimenting was if both `for` statements contained `array.length` and the 2D array was a 5x10, it would print it as a 5x5, but with `array[0].length` it would print a correct 5x10.

So why does this little adjustment fix everything?

Comment: The crucial issue is that a 2D array is an array of arrays.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're trying to troll.. @__@, I'm well aware of that though.

Answer (score 5):

You're dealing with a *2D* array. `array.length` essentially gives you the number of rows, but `array[0].length` gives the number of *columns* (at least for non-jagged arrays). Take this example:

```
String[][] array = new String[][]{
    {"1","2"},
    {"3","4"},
    {"5","6"}
};
```

Here `array.length` is `3` (the entire 2D-array is composed of *three* 1D-arrays), but `array[0].length` is `2` (the length of *each constituent array*). Your first `for`-loop loops over the whole array-of-arrays, but your second loops over each *constituent* array that is encountered by the outer loop. Therefore, the inner loop should only loop up to (but not including) **`array[0].length`**.

Comment: If I changed it to `array[i].length` instead of `array[0].length` what would happen?

Comment: Nothing in this case - because it is a *square* array, so `array[i].length` will always be the same. If you had a jagged array you would have to do that.

Comment: Same as in? And by jagged I assume you mean:                             136                                                                 258                                                                 479

Comment: Same as in `array[i].length` will always be the same number for each `i` (assuming `i` is in range). In your case it will always be **`10`**. Jagged arrays are explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271540/java-jagged-array).

Comment: What if it contained `array.length` instead, what would be the difference.

Comment: Well then we would have a problem, because `array.length` is the total number of arrays that your 2D-array contains, but this doesn't have to be (and isn't in this case) equal to *length of these individual arrays* (`array[0].length`), so you will likely get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` or not loop over the entire array (in this case the latter).

Comment: Ah so it should be recognized as `array[i].length` to make sure the column is verified.

Answer (score 4):

Aa 2D array is like a matrix, represented by an array of arrays of `String` objects. When you define:

```
array = new String [5][10];
```

You are saying "I want an array of 5 string arrays with a length of 10", something like this:

```
 [String[10]][String[10]][String[10]][String[10]][String[10]]
```

Here:

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length;i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<array[0].length;j++) //I'd recommend j < array[i] here. Nothing 
                                        //changes on this case, but it would bring 
                                        //some trouble if the second dimention of the 
                                        //array was not the same for every case.
    {
        System.out.print(array[i][j]="*");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

The first for iterates over the array of five `String` arrays, that's why i goes from `0` to `4` and the array's length is 5. The second for iterates over the indexes of the `String[]` objects contained on the first array (the one with length `5`). This arrays have a length of `10` elements.

Comment: So what if I changed the second `for` to `array.length` what would the problem be?

Comment: Since there are 5 rows and 10 columns in this 2D array. Therefore, in the first loop each element you get is a row with 10 strings.
So, you want the second loop to run 10 times. Hence you do array[0].length which evaluates to 10 and not array.length which evaluates to 5

Answer (score 0):

It's because `array[0]` is actually a `String[]` array.

Answer (score 0):

The second `for` statement is required to get the number of columns in the array, 10 in this case.

- `array.length` - no. of rows
- `array[0].length` - no of columns

This array is assumed square rather than jagged so using `array[0]` is deemed safe to use in this example.

Let's look at the **wrong** way:
By doing this:

```
for (int i=0; i<array.length;i++) {
    for(int j=0; j < array.length;j++) {
        System.out.print(array[i][j]="*");
    }
}
```

you are only displaying 5 x 5 entries, missing half the number of entries. Also if the array had originally been 10 rows x 5 colums, an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` would have been throws as the number of columns would have been exceeded when `j = 5`.

A convenient way of displaying 2D arrays is:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

Comment: So if both `for` statements contained `array.length` what would be the issue? Would it just create a "square-type" table by just taking the number of rows as the number of columns?

Comment: By using `array.length` in the second `for` loop, only half the `String` values would be assigned & the rest would remain as `null`.