# The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) int, int[]

Tags: java, int, arguments, undefined, operator-keyword

Just trying to understand what's wrong with my code. Much appreciate ur help :)

```
public class lab5 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] m = new int[5][5];

    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
            m[i][j] = i + j;
            System.out.println(m[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
     }
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
        sum = sum + m[i];    **// here i get error "The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) int, int[]"**
    double average = sum / m.length;

    System.out.println("Average value of array element is " + average);

}
```

}

Comment: Error message says it all. You're trying to add an `int` value and an *array*, which of course is because the value of `m[i]` is a sub-array.

Answer (score 2):

`m` is a 2-dimensional array.

`m[i]` is a 1-dimensional array.

`+` operator makes no sense if the arguments are a number (`sum`) and a 1-dimensional array (`m[i]`).

---

*Update:* to calculate the average of a 2-dimensional array, you need to have two (nested) loops. Much like you already have in the first part of your program.

```
int sum = 0;
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
        sum = sum + m[i][j];
        ++count;
    }
}
double average = ((double) sum) / count;
```

The code above accounts for [jagged arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10271540/2170192), but does **not** handle [integer overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

---

Here's an amended homework for you :) 
Try to simplify the code above, removing the `count` variable (you can do this if the 2-dimensional array is a matrix rather than a jagged array).

Try to also handle a possible integer overflow correctly (hint: change the type of `sum` to something bigger than `int`).

Comment: how can solve it? i just started java and i dont really know how to do it work normally

Comment: can you please explain what is the intended result? 
Do you want to compute an average through all the items of the `m` matrix? 
Or do you want the average of a certain row? Or do you want the average of every row separately?

Comment: generally speaking, you must provide 2 indexes in order to get an integer value from a 2-dim array. E.g. `m[i][0]` will give you a number (rather than an array) which you could add to `sum`. But the intention of the program is not clear...

Comment: average through all the items of the m, matrix i guess (my task sounds like calculate the average of  array elements)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to calculate the sum of the array, you need 2 for loops.
Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
    sum = sum + m[i][j];
  }
}
```