# Give values to nested maps java

Tags: java

I have a nested map (map in/of map) with two string keys. Essentially what I do is that I have a set of nodes and I find the shortest route between them. However I need to store them and later use them, so I did the following:

```
private Map<String, Map<String,Object>> TravelTime = 
new HashMap<String, Map<String,Object>>();
```

I use a loop to give values to this Map, where ParkingDests is a set of keys (String) of another HashMap:

```
ParkingDests = ParkingAttributes.keySet().size();
for (int i = 0;i< ParkingDests; i++){
    for (int j = 0;j< ParkingDests; j++){

        <code> TravelTime.put(keyone,keytwo,Shortest) </code>

    }
}
```

I suppose what I need is something like:

```
TraveTime.put(ParkingDests(i),ParkingDest(j), ShortestRoute)
```

However I cannot find a way to do it. 
I am aware of the Guava Table (and I know that it is exactly what I need), however I would prefer to find a solution in this context.

Comment: Are you sure what you want is not: `HashMap<Pair<String, String>, Object>`?

Comment: Could you give us the type of `ParkingDests`?

Comment: You might want to look into a question about Java sparse matrices http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390181/sparse-matrices-arrays-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to check to see if the secondary HashMap is added in before you add a new route.  Here, I'm assuming ParkingDests is a String array.  I also assume, that your  tags means you're wrapping this loop in some code that generates the ShortestRoute object.  Definitely no need to store it as a generic Object, but I'm sure you were just simplifying your question nicely for our benefit :)

```
for (int i = 0;i< ParkingDests; i++){
    for (int j = 0;j< ParkingDests; j++){

        <code>
        second = TravelTime.get(ParkingDests[i])
        if(second == null) {
            second = new HashMap<String, Object>()
            TravelTime.put(ParkingDests[i], second);
        }
        second.put(ParkingDests[j],Shortest);
        </code>

    }
}
```

Also note, I recommend against using the keySet as ParkingDests like your edited question.  You don't get guaranteed order from that.  You should keep the ParkingDests as an array.

Comment: I think this is it! I changed the ParkingDests to arrays tnx for the advice!! Indeed I scaled my code and indeed thats what it does ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a Graph data structure. You could use [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/alg/DijkstraShortestPath.html). It has an implementation for the [Dijkstra Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) which calculates the shortest path. The nodes would be your ParkingDests and the weight of the edges would be your traveltime of distance. 
The optimal route would be a subgraph. Have fun.

Comment: I use the Graph structure to calculate the shortest path, but I need to store the cost/route for the Origin-Destination to be used for some specific pairs as an object that contains travel information from a node to all others ;). Thank you very much for the suggestion.