# Get Item by Index

Tags: java, data-structures

What is the best data structure, in java, for getting and setting items by index?

I was initially using ArrayList, but the problem is sometimes, I need to insert an element that is greater than the size of arraylist, like:

```
pseudocode
array = new ArrayList();
array.set(10, object);
```

Obviously this returns out an error. I could initialize the array with sentinel values, but using:

```
array.size()
```

will always say that my array is filled to the brim. Obviously it is just filled with sentinel values.

Comment: [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Comment: @Maroun Maroun I reload the page, waiting for someone to state Map as the answer so I could accept, and all I see is your comment increasing upvotes :D

Comment: Could you tell why you need to insert something at a point that is not exactly after the last element in the list but "further on"? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390181/sparse-matrices-arrays-in-java) might be of interest if you are actually looking for a sparse list, otherwise go with a `Map`.

Comment: @Secret you can also delete the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you always know the index at which you're inserting the value, then using a concrete implementation of the `Map` interface is usually the way to go.

The advantage of this set of classes is that, with knowledge of the index (or the `Key` in this context), you can directly retrieve the object from memory in O(1) time. That means no searching.

For example:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

map.put("KEY", "VALUE");

String key = "KEY";

// Do some processing..

String value = map.get(key);

// value variable now contains "VALUE".
```

Have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to get a really solid grasp of how to use this set of classes.

Comment: In this instance you would probably use `HashMap<Integer, String>();`.

Comment: I usually just program to an interface, on the off chance I need to take advantage of Liskov's contribution to our field.

Comment: What I meant was that the key should be Integer instead of String.

Comment: Ah. Erm, yeah I don't see why not.

Answer (score 0):

It depends (as so often...). When your indices are within a certain reasonable range and you will use almost all of them, use an array with proper size:

```
Object[] items = new Object[MAX_INDEX];
```

If your range is much larger and many of your array slots will not be used, a `Map` (as already stated in other answers) is what you might need. `HashMap` is one possible implementation:

```
Map<Integer, Object> items = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
```