# May I shrink an array to save memory in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

For instance, I have a 2-D array:

1 2 3 4 5

6 7 8 9 10

11 12

It's an 3 by 5 array. However, in the third row, I only need to fill two cells. The remaining ones are unnecessary, but it's created when initializing the array.

The reason I want to so this is that my actual array's row is very long, so that potentially wastes a big chunk of memory, because i only need to use two cells in the 3rd row.

Is there a way to shorten the third row to contain two cells only after the array is filled up?

I am not sure it's possible, or it's the best way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Java arrays can be jagged.

Comment: You could use an array with linked-lists attached but unless there is a huge difference in length I don't think this would be worth it. Maintaining a linked list would add a lot more additional overhead as well making it harder to find a value in your list.

Comment: You can always write your own implementation of 2D array.

Comment: Rather than declaring a `new Thing[X][Y]`, declare a `new Thing[X]` and then loop and set the arrays to the correct size.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sparse matrices / arrays in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390181/sparse-matrices-arrays-in-java)

Comment: Could you be more specific on "declare a new Thing[X] and then loop and set the arrays to the correct size"? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't shrink arrays in java because you can't change their length, however you can set the inner arrays of a 2-D array to arrays of different lengths.

```
int[][] ar = new int[3][];
ar[0] = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
ar[1] = new int[]{6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
ar[2] = new int[]{11, 12};
```

Comment: That's cool. But don't understand how it's do memory allotment when the column is not specified in the initialization.

Comment: In Java, 2D arrays are actually arrays of arrays. `new int[3][3]` will allocate 3 `int[]` arrays, 1 `int[][]` array and then put `int[]` arrays into `int[][]` array.

Comment: @user697911 there is no such thing as a nD array in Java. There are just arrays of arrays.

Comment: However, I am still having a trouble, because my code has to fill up the array cells in a two-for loop. for(int i=0; i<n; i++){ for(int j=0; J<N; j++){ ar[i][j] = new int[]{...} }}. This won't work as the above way.

Comment: @user697911 you should be able to create the inner arrays inside the outer for loop and then populate them inside the inner for loop, assuming you know how large each inner array will be.

Comment: @Alex Exactly. I got it. for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
   boolean[] column = new boolean[N];
   for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
    column[i] = false;
   } 
   ar[i] = column;
  }