# Java N-Dimensional Sparse Matrix

Tags: java, optimization, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a 4-dimensional huge sparse matrix and I need to know the best data structure to manage my information using Java. 
I read from this topic [Sparse matrices / arrays in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390181/sparse-matrices-arrays-in-java) and it says that Tries is better than Hash Tables when matrix is so formatted. Unluckly the most authoritative answer talks about 2D-dimension matrices and I haven't found anything about N-dimensional ones.

Thank you in advance for your reply