# Filter TreeMap with integer array key and perform arithmetic operations

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, java-8, sparse-matrix

I write a complex program in Java where I need to manage many large sparse matrix that contain integer values.
Example:

```
int A[][][][];
int B[][][];
int C[][];
```

In order to saving memory, space, etc, I decided to store this data in TreeMap. I know that exist a lot of libraries that do it better but I would try to implement my personal solution.
First of all I created a class Index that identifies the indeces of this array without knowing how many they are.

```
public class Index implements Comparable<Index> {
    private final int[] index;

    public Index(int ... index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    @Override
    public int toCompare(Index i) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Obviously I've used this class to define my three Maps in this way:

```
Map <Index, Integer> mapA = new TreeMap <> ();
Map <Index, Integer> mapB = new TreeMap <> ();
Map <Index, Integer> mapC = new ...
```

Now, I need to store the data from the matrix that I previous create to those Maps. The most easy way is use 4/3/2/.. loops, but I accept with pleasure others solutions.

```
for(int s = 0; s < s_max; s++) {
            for(int c = 0; c < c_max; c++) {
                for(int o = 0; o < o_max; o++) {
                    for(int d = 0; d < d_max; d++) {
                        mapA.put(new Index(s,c,o,d), A[s][c][o][d]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The focus of the problem is when I need to retrieve the data, but let's me explain. The more usually operations between those maps are multiplications and additions considering them as matrix or arrays. I can't make 6(..) nested loops every times that I need to perform operations likes this below (I can't insert images because my reputation is still low):

http://postimg.org/image/7m8v0kiwn/

My questions are:

1. How can I filter my values from keys?
2. There is a way (maybe using lambda expression) to perform this type of operations?
3. Any advices about this problem?

Comment: Why do you think that copying your arrays to a TreeMap will save memory? Also, using arrays as keys to a map doesn't make sense since arrays are created using dynamic classes which don't override equals and hashcode so you can't find something in the Map unless you have the reference to the original arrays that were used as keys.

Comment: You need to be much clearer about your problem, your current solution, why you are trying to do it in this way and what the problem is with your current solution.

Comment: @bot the arrays are sparse, so using a different structure could save memory.

Comment: I chose TreeMap instead of HashMap beacuse I've read that the second ones are more expensive in terms of calculation of hash in huge arrays. The article that you can find below talks about of Trie (instead of HashMap) and I supposed than a tree-like structure could be better than hash-like one. <br>
From:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390181/sparse-matrices-arrays-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you don’t need to create an `Index` class; the type you need [already exists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/IntBuffer.html).

From the documentation of [`IntBuffer.compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/IntBuffer.html#compareTo-java.nio.IntBuffer-):

> Two int buffers are compared by comparing their sequences of remaining elements lexicographically, without regard to the starting position of each sequence within its corresponding buffer.

So if you [wrap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/IntBuffer.html#wrap-int:A-) integer array holding the indices and keep the position and limit at their defaults, the buffers will provide the desired behavior.

---

Performing the array to map conversion in a general way works, if you consider that in Java, each multi-dimensional array is also an instance of `Object[]`, regardless of their base type. I.e., the type `int[][]` is a subtype of `Object[]` whose elements are instances of `int[]` which is a subtype of `Object`. Further, `Object[][]` is a subtype of `Object[]` whose elements are of type `Object[]` which is a subtype of `Object`.

Therefore you can process all dimensions the same way as `Object[]` to traverse it and only have to care about the actual type at the *last* dimension, which is always `int[]` for any *n*-dimensional `int` array:

```
/** accepts all int arrays from one to 255 dimensions */
public static TreeMap<IntBuffer,Integer> toMap(Object array) {
    int dim=1;
    for(Class<?> cl=array.getClass(); ; cl=cl.getComponentType())
        if(Object[].class.isAssignableFrom(cl)) dim++;
        else if(cl==int[].class) break;
        else throw new IllegalArgumentException(array.getClass().getSimpleName());
    TreeMap<IntBuffer,Integer> map=new TreeMap<>();
    fill(map, new int[dim], 0, array);
    return map;
}

private static void fill(TreeMap<IntBuffer, Integer> map, int[] i, int ix, Object array) {
    int next=ix+1;
    i[ix]=0;
    if(next<i.length)
        for(Object part: (Object[])array) {
            if(part!=null) fill(map, i, next, part);
            i[ix]++;
        }
    else
        for(int val: (int[])array) {
            if(val!=0) map.put(IntBuffer.wrap(i.clone()), val);
            i[ix]++;
        }
}
```

This solution handles the dimensions recursively though a non-recursive one is in principle possible. However, the recursion depth is naturally limited to the number of dimensions of the array/matrix.

It will put only non-zero values into the map and also skip any `null` sub-array, thus it doesn’t mind if the array representation is already sparse.

An example usage might look like

```
int[][][][] array=new int[5][5][5][5];
array[1][2][3][4]=42;
array[4][3][2][1]=1234;
TreeMap<IntBuffer, Integer> sparse=toMap(array);
sparse.forEach((index,value)-> {
    for(int ix:index.array()) System.out.print("["+ix+']');
    System.out.println("="+value);
});
```

which will print:

```
[1][2][3][4]=42
[4][3][2][1]=1234
```

Another example:

```
int[][] id = {
  {1},
  {0, 1},
  {0, 0, 1},
  {0, 0, 0, 1},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
};
TreeMap<IntBuffer, Integer> idAsMap = toMap(id);
System.out.println(idAsMap.size()+" non-zero values");
idAsMap.forEach((index,value)-> {
    for(int ix:index.array()) System.out.print("["+ix+']');
    System.out.println("="+value);
});
```

will print:

```
7 non-zero values
[0][0]=1
[1][1]=1
[2][2]=1
[3][3]=1
[4][4]=1
[5][5]=1
[6][6]=1
```